# How to match field value in response when there are multiple fields with the same name?

Tags: karate

```
[
    {
        "key": "test1",
        "category": "test",
        "name": "test1",
        "translations": 
        {
            "english": "eng"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "test2",
        "category": "test",
        "name": "test1",
        "translations": 
        {
            "english": "eng2",
            "german": "German"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "test3",
        "category": "power",
        "name": "test1",
        "translations": 
        {
            "EN_lang": "jik"
        }
    }
]
```

Here, we have multiple field's are with different values and we have to match value in translations (field position will change on every call)

Comment: you can always get an index value

Answer (score 1):

You have to be clear about what you want to assert. Hint, the new `contains deep` (available in 0.9.6.RC4) can help:

```
* match response contains deep { key: 'test2', translations: { english: 'eng2' } }
```

Else you should look at transforming the JSON into a shape where it is easier to do the assertions you want: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms