# Karate: compare csv data with api response

Tags: karate

I have a use case where I want to assert on a API response and compare it with the csv data.

Step1:

```
Csv file: *test.csv*
id,date,fullname,cost,country,code
1,02-03-2002,user1,$200,Canada,CAN
2, 04-05-2016,user2,$1500,United States, USA
```

I read the csv file and store it in a variable

- def var1 = read(test.csv)

So now, var1 is a list of jsons based on my csv

```
var1 = [
{
"id":1,
"date":"02-03-2002",
"fullname": "user1",
"cost": "$200",
"country": "Canada",
"code": "CAN"
},
{
"id":2,
"date":"04-05-2016",
"fullname": "user2",
"cost": "$1500",
"country": "United States",
"code": "USA"
}
]
```

Step2:
I hit my api and get a response

```
Given url "https://dummyurl.com
Given path "/userdetails"
When method get
Then status 200
* def apiResponse = response
```

Step 3:
My api returns a list response which is:

```
{
"id":1,
"date":"02-03-2002",
"fullname": "user1",
"cost": "$200",
"country": { 
  "name": "Canada",
  "code": "CAN"
  }
},
{
"id":2,
"date":"05-04-2012",
"fullname": "user2",
"cost": "$1500",
"country": { 
  "name": "United States",
  "code": "USA"
  }
},
...and more 100 records..
]
```

Step 4:
So there are two assertions now which I wanted to perform

1. Get the count of csvresponse and apiresponse and compare which I did using the **.length** operator
2. Secondly, I want to confirm if each csv records are matching with each api response.
   And if possible in my case **id** key from csv and apiresponse is primary key, so if I can iterate on id and match the api response for any discrepancy.

Let me know if this is readable for you and if I was able to explain my use case.
Thanks for your earlier response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read up on the `match contains` syntax, that's all you need: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains

So this one line should be enough:

```
* match var1 contains response
```

Also look at this answer in case the new `contains deep` helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103746/143475

Try to avoid iterating, it is not needed for most API tests. But you can certainly do it. Look at these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567262/143475

Also read this - because I suspect you are trying to over-complicate your tests. Please don't. Write tests where your are 100% sure of the "shape" of the response as far as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

And please please read the docs. It is worth it.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your prompt response, I am surely going through the documentation and will try looking at all the links you shared.

Comment: match is not working for me as my csv data is not nested and my api response has a nested json. I am thinking to try having some logic

Comment: @NachiK look, this is exactly what I was trying to tell you when I marked your first question as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449166/143475 - all the best

Comment: But may be I am getting it wrong or unable to explain you, about my comparison of two list based on conditional logic.. may be I will give it a shot with some function. Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried with your suggestion of reading a CSV - reading csv is giving "\" in the response since my csv has nested option, is there any way I can remove it using a replace option.

Comment: @NachiK no. don't use csv unless you know what you're doing

Comment: I am trying to read a CSV and compare with a api list response, the csv and api both have same fields. Both have nested fields, but when I read my csv and print the response - I get like this ["id":"123", "name":"test","data":"{\"status\":\"Yes\", \"code\":\"Red\"}"].   My csv is: id, name,data ---- first row is: 123,test,"{""Status"":""Yes"",""code"":""Red""}"

Comment: @NachiK the linked answer says a) don't use csv for nested structures b) how to escape nested content if needed. if this is not possible, please look for another framework. I have nothing more to add